# How To Save auto increment id in another table using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
public function register() {
    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
        $u = $_POST['uname'];
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->db->select('uname');
        $this->db->from('login');
        $this->db->where(array('uname' => $u));
        $query1 = $this->db->get();        
        if (!$query1->num_rows() == 1) {
            $data = array(
                'fname' => $_POST['fname'],
                'lname' => $_POST['lname'],
                'dob' => $_POST['dob'],
                'gender' => $_POST['gender'],
                'email' => $_POST['email']
            );
            $this->load->database();
            $this->db->insert('user', $data);
            $data1 = array(

                //'User_idUser'=>$_POST[$query1], 
                'uname' => $_POST['uname'],
                'upass' => $_POST['upass']

            );

            $this->db->insert('login', $data1);
        } else {

            $_SESSION["ex"] = "User All Ready Exists";
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('register');
}
```

I want to get auto increment id of user table to save in login table as a foreign key to identify which user is currently logging. the code is running perfectly.

the user table is a parent table and 
login table is a child table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User following code to get ID of last insert operation.

```
$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

And use `$inser_id` to add it to any table you want.

So if I open the commented line of your code,

```
$data1 = array(
        'User_idUser' => $insert_id,  // Assuming that UseridUser is your columne to store the Autoincremented user id from previous insert query.
        'uname' => $_POST['uname'],
        'upass' => $_POST['upass']
    );
```

Comment: where should i add $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id(); this code

Comment: @gpushpitha, sorry I forgot to put that variable. I have updated my answer. Your column in login table for userid is `User_idUser` right?